# Adjusting Month Specific SQL Query to Iterate Across all Months Greater than Base Month

Tags: sql, greenplum

I've inherited a query that has parameters which specify pulls data for a single desired month. The extract then gets manually added to previous month's extract in Excel. I'd like to eliminate the manual portion by adjusting the existing query to iterate across all months greater than a given base month, then (if this is what makes most sense) unioning the individual "final" outputs.

My attempt was to add the entire block of code for each specific month to the existing code, and then run it together. The idea was that I'd just paste in a new block each new month. I knew this was very inefficient, but I don't have the luxury of learning how to do it efficiently, so if it worked I'd be happy.

I ran into problems because the existing query has two subqueries which then are used to create a final table, and I couldn't figure out how to retain the final table at the end of the code so that it could be referenced in a union later (fwiw, I was attempting to use a Select Into for that final table).

```
with eligibility_and_customer_type AS                           
(SELECT DISTINCT ON(sub_id, mbr_sfx_id)                         
     sub_id      AS subscriber_id                           
    , mbr_sfx_id  AS member_suffix_id                           
    , src_mbr_key                           
    , ctdv.cstmr_typ_cd                         
    , gdv.grp_name                          
FROM adw_common.cstmr_typ_dim_vw ctdv                           
JOIN adw_common.mbr_eligty_by_mo_fact_vw                            
    ON ctdv.cstmr_typ_key = mbr_eligty_by_mo_fact_vw.cstmr_typ_key                          
    AND mbr_eligty_yr = '2018'                          
    AND mbr_eligty_mo = '12'                              
JOIN adw_common.prod_cat_dim_vw                         
    ON prod_cat_dim_vw.prod_cat_key = mbr_eligty_by_mo_fact_vw.prod_cat_key                         
    AND prod_cat_dim_vw.prod_cat_cd = 'M'                           
JOIN adw_common.mbr_dim_abr                         
    ON mbr_eligty_by_mo_fact_vw.mbr_key = mbr_dim_abr.mbr_key                           
JOIN consumer.facets_xref_abr fxf                           
    ON mbr_dim_abr.src_mbr_key = fxf.source_member_key                          
JOIN adw_common.grp_dim_vw gdv                          
    ON gdv.grp_key=mbr_eligty_by_mo_fact_vw.grp_key),                           

facets_ip as                            
 (select distinct cl.meme_ck                            

  FROM gpgen_cr_ai.cmc_clcl_claim_abr cl                            
           /* LEFT JOIN gpgen_cr_ai.cmc_clhp_hosp_abr ch                            
            ON cl.clcl_id = ch.clcl_id*/                            
            LEFT JOIN gpgen_cr_ai.cmc_cdml_cl_line cd                           
            ON cl.clcl_id = cd.clcl_id                          
            WHERE cd.pscd_id = '21'                         
            /*AND ch.clcl_id IS NULL*/                          
            AND cl.clcl_cur_sts NOT IN ('91','92')                          
            AND cl.clcl_low_svc_dt  >= '20181201'                       
               and cl.clcl_low_svc_dt <= '20181231'                     
       group by 1)                          


  select distinct c.meme_ck,                            
                  e.cstmr_typ_cd,
                  '201812' as Yearmo                         
  from facets_ip c                          
  left join eligibility_and_customer_type e                         
  on c.meme_ck = e.src_mbr_key;
```

The code above has date parameters that get updated when necessary.

The final output would be a version of the final table created above, but with results corresponding to, say, 201801 - present.

Comment: Are you wanting to preserve result set the code above ?

Answer (score 0):

If you provide:

1. DDL of the underlying tables
2. Sample Data of the underlying tables
3. Expected resultset
4. DBMS you are using

, then one would be able to provide the best solution here.

Without knowing them, and as you said you only care about dynamically looping through each month, here is one way you can utilize your code to loop it through in SQL Server. Please fill the variable @StartDate and @EndDate values and provide proper datatype for meme_ck and cstmr_typ_cd.

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#TempTable', N'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #TempTable
END

CREATE  TABLE   #TempTable
(
    meme_ck         <ProvideProperDataTypeHere>
    ,cstmr_typ_cd   <ProvideProperDataTypeHere>
    ,Yearmo         VARCHAR(10)
)

DECLARE @StartDate  DATE = '<Provide the first day of the start month>'
DECLARE @EndDate    DATE = '<Provide the end date inclusive>'

WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate
BEGIN

    DECLARE @MonthEndDate DATE = CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @StartDate)) <= @EndDate THEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @StartDate)) ELSE @EndDate END
    DECLARE @MonthYear VARCHAR(6) = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @StartDate, 112), 6)


    --This is your code which I am not touching without not knowing any detail about it. Just feeding the variables to make it dynamic
    ;with eligibility_and_customer_type AS                           
    (SELECT DISTINCT ON(sub_id, mbr_sfx_id)                         
         sub_id      AS subscriber_id                           
        , mbr_sfx_id  AS member_suffix_id                           
        , src_mbr_key                           
        , ctdv.cstmr_typ_cd                         
        , gdv.grp_name                          
    FROM adw_common.cstmr_typ_dim_vw ctdv                           
    JOIN adw_common.mbr_eligty_by_mo_fact_vw                            
        ON ctdv.cstmr_typ_key = mbr_eligty_by_mo_fact_vw.cstmr_typ_key                          
        AND mbr_eligty_yr = CAST(YEAR(@StartDate) AS VARCHAR(10))   -- NO need to cast if mbr_eligty_yr is an Integer
        AND mbr_eligty_mo = CAST(MONTH(@StartDate) AS VARCHAR(10))  -- NO need to cast if mbr_eligty_yr is an Integer
    JOIN adw_common.prod_cat_dim_vw                         
        ON prod_cat_dim_vw.prod_cat_key = mbr_eligty_by_mo_fact_vw.prod_cat_key                         
        AND prod_cat_dim_vw.prod_cat_cd = 'M'                           
    JOIN adw_common.mbr_dim_abr                         
        ON mbr_eligty_by_mo_fact_vw.mbr_key = mbr_dim_abr.mbr_key                           
    JOIN consumer.facets_xref_abr fxf                           
        ON mbr_dim_abr.src_mbr_key = fxf.source_member_key                          
    JOIN adw_common.grp_dim_vw gdv                          
        ON gdv.grp_key=mbr_eligty_by_mo_fact_vw.grp_key),                           

    facets_ip as                            
     (select distinct cl.meme_ck                            

      FROM gpgen_cr_ai.cmc_clcl_claim_abr cl                            
               /* LEFT JOIN gpgen_cr_ai.cmc_clhp_hosp_abr ch                            
                ON cl.clcl_id = ch.clcl_id*/                            
                LEFT JOIN gpgen_cr_ai.cmc_cdml_cl_line cd                           
                ON cl.clcl_id = cd.clcl_id                          
                WHERE cd.pscd_id = '21'                         
                /*AND ch.clcl_id IS NULL*/                          
                AND cl.clcl_cur_sts NOT IN ('91','92')                          
                AND cl.clcl_low_svc_dt  BETWEEN @StartDate AND @MonthEndDate                  
           group by 1)                    
      INSERT INTO #TempTable
      (
            meme_ck         
            ,cstmr_typ_cd   
            ,Yearmo         
      )
      select distinct c.meme_ck,                            
                      e.cstmr_typ_cd,
                      @MonthYear as Yearmo                         
      from facets_ip c                          
      left join eligibility_and_customer_type e                         
      on c.meme_ck = e.src_mbr_key; 


    SET @StartDate = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @StartDate)
END

SELECT * FROM #TempTable;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. See error: Error:7/8/2019 7:28:23 PM 0:00:00.069: ODBC Database Error: [DataDirect][ODBC Greenplum Wire Protocol driver][Greenplum]ERROR: syntax error at or near "IF"(Position 1; File scan.l; Line 979; Routine base_yyerror; )
loop_ip_census.sql:1: IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#TempTable', N'U') IS NOT NULL
Error:7/8/2019 7:28:27 PM 0:00:00.052: ODBC Database Error: [DataDirect][ODBC Greenplum Wire Protocol driver][Greenplum]ERROR: syntax error at or near "DROP"(Position 12; File scan.l; Line 979; Routine base_yyerror; )
loop_ip_census.sql:3:4:

Comment: As mentioned in the solution, the above solution is given for SQL Server. You should be able to use it using SSMS. If your source DBMS is different, please tag the appropriate DBMS against which you are trying to execute the query.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, but a lot of these terms are above my head. My team recently lost our data manager who typically handles this stuff. I typically do analytics and reporting, and am just trying to stay afloat with the query stuff. If it matters, I am executing the query on the TOAD DATA POINT software with a connection to a database called GREENPLUM.

Comment: @Acemanhattan please provide proper tag in your post, someone with Greenplum experience might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough information on your tables to really create an optimal solution.  The solutions I am providing just have a single parameter (table name) and for your solution, you will need to pass in an additional parameter for the date filter.

The idea of "looping" is not something you'll need to do in Greenplum.  That is common for OLTP databases like SQL Server or Oracle that can't handle big data very well and have to process smaller amounts at a time.

For these example solutions, a table is needed with some data in it.

```
    CREATE TABLE public.foo
    (id integer,
     fname text,
     lname text)
    DISTRIBUTED BY (id);

    insert into foo values (1, 'jon', 'roberts'), 
    (2, 'sam', 'roberts'),
    (3, 'jon', 'smith'),
    (4, 'sam', 'smith'),
    (5, 'jon', 'roberts'),
    (6, 'sam', 'roberts'),
    (7, 'jon', 'smith'),
    (8, 'sam', 'smith');
```

**Solution 1:** Learn how functions work in the database.  Here is a quick example of how it would work.

Create a function that does the Create Table As Select (CTAS) where you pass in a parameter.

Note: You can't execute DDL statements in a function directly so you have to use "EXECUTE" instead.

```
    create or replace function fn_test(p_table_name text) returns void as
    $$
    declare
        v_sql text;
    begin
        v_sql :='drop table if exists ' || p_table_name;
        execute v_sql;

        v_sql := 'create table ' || p_table_name || ' with (appendonly=true, compresstype=quicklz) as
        with t as (select * from foo)
        select * from t
        distributed by (id)';
        execute v_sql;
    end;
    $$
    language plpgsql;
```

Execute the function with a simple select statement.

```
    select fn_test('foo3');
```

Notice how I pass in a table name that will be created when you execute the function.

**Solution 2:** Use psql variables

Create a sql file name "test.sql" with the following contents.

```
drop table if exists :p_table_name;

create table :p_table_name with (appendonly=true, compresstype=quicklz) as
with t as (select * from foo)
select * from t
distributed by (id);
```

Next, you execute psql and pass in the variable p_table_name.

```
psql -f test.sql -v p_table_name=foo4
psql:test.sql:1: NOTICE:  table "foo4" does not exist, skipping
DROP TABLE
SELECT 8
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!